# Normalizing Grayscale image magnitude to one

Tags: matlab, image-processing, fft

I want to normalize the magnitude of grayscale images to one on MATLAB ([reference](http://www.comm.utoronto.ca/~dkundur/course_info/signals/notes/Kundur_FourierMagPhase.pdf))

Slide 18 shows what the result should look like, but for some reason when I run my code I get a complete black image output, here's my code:

```
 % Load images
 f1 = (imread('f1.jpg'));
 f2 = (imread('f2.jpg'));

 %compute 2D FT of F1 and F2

 F1 = fft2(double(f1));
 F2 = fft2(double(f2));

 % Find magnitude and phase of the two images

 F1Mag = abs(F1);
 F1Phase = angle(F1);

 F2Mag = abs(F2);
 F2Phase = angle(F2);

 % set magnitudes to 1

 Gone = exp(1j*F1Phase);
 Gtwo = exp(1j*F2Phase);

 %invert to image

 gone = uint8(ifft2(Gone));
 gtwo = uint8(ifft2(Gtwo));
```

I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong, any help/suggestions would be amazing. Thank you

Comment: Why are you casting it as `uint8` at the end?

Comment: the original image is in uint8, so in order to get an image back out of the inverse fourier i have to put it back in uint8. Eitherway, that part is not the issue because even if i remove that part i still get a fully black image out

Comment: How are you visualizing your image? And yes, the `uint8` crushes all of the values to `0` so it is as least *part* of the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are casting your data (which consists of negative numbers as well as numbers < 1) to a `uint8` which is effectively causing all of your values to be set to `0` resulting in a black image. You want to instead keep the image as a `double` and use `imagesc` to display the result.

```
f1 = imread('cameraman.tif');
F1 = fft2(f1);

% Set the magnitude to 1
G1 = exp(1j * angle(F1));

% Convert back to image domain and take the real component
g1 = real(ifft2(G1));

% Display the result using imagesc so it's scaled
imagesc(g1);
colormap gray;
```

[image]

If you really want the output to be `uint8`, you'll want to first use `mat2gray` to normalize the image, and then scale it by `255` *before* casting it as a `uint8`.

```
g2 = uint8(mat2gray(g1) * 255);
```

Comment: OH MY GOD! That makes a lot more sense thank you so much